# How to remove the 'disabled' attribute if another textbox has a value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two textboxes (Qty, Empties) as shown below. I would like to remove the **disabled** attribute if the Qty text box has a value. How do I do this with JS?

```
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qtyEmpty[]" 
             disabled id="<?php echo "qtyEmpty" . $b++; ?>" 
             min="1" max="<?php echo $case_true_quantity; ?>" />
```

[image: Grid]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should solve your problem

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="sPriceRewards" id="sPriceRewards" value="" />
<input type="text" name="sReward1" value="" class="inputReward" />
```

JS code:

```
$('#sPriceRewards').on('input', function() {

if($(this).val().length)
   $('.inputReward').prop('disabled', true);
else
    $('.inputReward').prop('disabled', false);
});
```